# Weird D3D9 Bug when drawing

Tags: direct3d

So I'm making a program that hooks into a games D3D9::Present to draw a clock and ran into a problem, sometimes, such as when I'm in-game, the colors will appear very bright and it will look terrible.

Here is what I mean

Normal:

[image: normal clock]

Bugged:

[image]

and this is what i call after making a stateblock..

```
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_VERTEXBLEND, D3DVBF_DISABLE);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_INDEXEDVERTEXBLENDENABLE, 0);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_MULTISAMPLEANTIALIAS, 0);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXCOORDINDEX, 0);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, D3DTTFF_DISABLE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);
    m_Device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_POINT);
    m_Device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_POINT);
    m_Device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
    m_Device->SetTexture(3, nullptr);
    m_Device->SetTexture(0, nullptr);
    m_Device->SetTexture(1, nullptr);
    m_Device->SetVertexShader(nullptr);
    m_Device->SetPixelShader(nullptr);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_FALSE); //D3DZB_TRUE
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FILLMODE, D3DFILL_SOLID);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SHADEMODE, D3DSHADE_GOURAUD);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE, 0);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE); //D3DCULL_CCW
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZFUNC, D3DCMP_LESSEQUAL);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FOGENABLE, 0);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SPECULARENABLE, 0);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_STENCILENABLE, 0);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CLIPPING, 0); //1
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, 0);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_COLORVERTEX, 1);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CLIPPLANEENABLE, 0); //1
    m_Device->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, 1);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA); //D3DBLEND_ONE
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA); //D3DBLEND_ZERO
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHATESTENABLE, 1);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, 0x08);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC, D3DCMP_GREATEREQUAL);
```

I'm drawing the clock's stuff with m_Device->DrawPrimitiveUP with a D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN

so my question is...how do you figure out what's causing this problem? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding this render state :D

```
    //Dis is fix for d3d9 appearing brighter??? or * 2.2 tha color orsoemthing called gammar correction
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRGBWRITEENABLE, 0);
```